# Listview in Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragmentactivity

I have a clickable listview in an activity. What I want is when I click from the list, it will go to a Fragment. Does anyone know how it is done?

Also, if there's a way when the user click from the list, it will open a new activity.

EDIT: Here are my codes.

```
        Activity_list.java

        package com.example.beminix.dcar;


        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.SearchView;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import java.util.ArrayList;

        public class Activity_list extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
            EstablishmentAdapter adapter = null;
            ArrayList<Establishments> establishments = null;
            ListView myEstListView;
            SearchView mySearchView = null ;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

                establishments = new ArrayList<>();
                establishments = populateEstablishmentsData(establishments);
                mySearchView = (SearchView) findViewById( R.id.mySearchView ) ;
                myEstListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myEstListView);
                adapter = new EstablishmentAdapter(this, establishments);
                myEstListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                mySearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                        // Here implement search logic
                        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                if(getSupportActionBar() != null)
                {
                    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
                    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                }
                ListView your_list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myEstListView);

            }

            private ArrayList<Establishments> populateEstablishmentsData(ArrayList<Establishments> establishments) {
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Art Gallery", 1, R.drawable.art_gallery_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("ATM", 2, R.drawable.atm_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Bakery", 3, R.drawable.bakery_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Bank",4, R.drawable.bank_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Bar",5, R.drawable.bar_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Book Store",6, R.drawable.book_store_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Bus Station/Bus Terminal",7, R.drawable.bus_terminal_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Cafe",8, R.drawable.cafe_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Car Services",9, R.drawable.car_services_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Car Retail Store",10, R.drawable.car_services_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Cemetery",11, R.drawable.cemetery_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Department Store",12, R.drawable.department_store_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Electronics Store",13, R.drawable.electronic_store_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Fast Food Chain",14, R.drawable.fast_food_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Fire Station",15, R.drawable.fire_station_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Flower Shop",16, R.drawable.flowershop_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Gas Station",17, R.drawable.gas_station_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Government Office",18, R.drawable.gov_office_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Gym",19, R.drawable.gym_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Hospital",20, R.drawable.hospital_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Hotel",21, R.drawable.hotel_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Ice Cream Shop",22, R.drawable.ice_cream_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Insurance Agency",23, R.drawable.insurance_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Jewelry Store",24, R.drawable.jewelry_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Laundry Shop Services",25, R.drawable.laundry_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Library",26, R.drawable.library_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Museum",27, R.drawable.museum_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Park",28, R.drawable.park_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Pet Store",29, R.drawable.pet_store_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Pharmacy",30, R.drawable.pharmacy_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Place of Worship",31, R.drawable.place_of_worship_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Police Station",32, R.drawable.police_station_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Restaurant",33, R.drawable.restaurant_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("School",34, R.drawable.school_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Shoes Store",35, R.drawable.shoe_store_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Shopping Mall",36, R.drawable.shopping_mall_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Spa",10, R.drawable.spa_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Travel Agency",37, R.drawable.travel_service_icon));
                establishments.add(new Establishments("Zoo",38, R.drawable.zoo_icon));
                return establishments;
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Establishments c = adapter.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(Activity_list.this, " " + c.geteName() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               //startActivity(new Intent(this, establishments[position].activityClass));
               // Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondFragment.class);
                //startActivity(intent);

               // android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home)
                    finish();
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

            }

            private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
                    String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString(); //text of position selected
                }



            };

        }

    EstablishmentAdapter.java


    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Filter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class EstablishmentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Establishments> {
        ArrayList<Establishments> establishments, tempEstablishment, suggestions;

        public EstablishmentAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Establishments> objects) {
            super(context, R.layout.customer_row, R.id.tvCustomer, objects);
            this.establishments = objects;
            this.tempEstablishment = new ArrayList<Establishments>(objects);
            this.suggestions = new ArrayList<Establishments>(objects);

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return initView(position, convertView, parent);
        }


        private View initView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Establishments establish = getItem(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                if (parent == null)
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.customer_row, null);
                else
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.customer_row, parent, false);
            }
            TextView txtCustomer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCustomer);
            ImageView ivCustomerImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivCustomerImage);
            if (txtCustomer != null)
                txtCustomer.setText(establish.geteName() + " " );


            if (ivCustomerImage != null)
                ivCustomerImage.setImageResource(establish.getEstPhoto());


            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return myFilter;
        }
        Filter myFilter =new Filter() {
            @Override
            public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                Establishments customer =(Establishments)resultValue ;
                return customer.geteName() + " ";
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                if (constraint != null) {
                    suggestions.clear();
                    for (Establishments cust : tempEstablishment) {
                        if (cust.geteName().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                            suggestions.add(cust);
                        }
                    }

                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    filterResults.values = suggestions;
                    filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
                    return filterResults;
                } else {
                    return new FilterResults();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                ArrayList<Establishments> c =  (ArrayList<Establishments> )results.values ;
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    clear();
                    for (Establishments cust : c) {
                        add(cust);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    clear();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        };
    }

Establishments.java

    package com.example.beminix.dcar;

/**
 * Created by Beminix on 09/02/2017.
 */



public class Establishments {
    private String estName = "";
    private int id = 0;
    private int estPhoto = -1;

    public Establishments(String ename, int id, int pic) {
        this.estName = ename;
        this.id = id;
        this.estPhoto = pic;

    }

    public String geteName() {
        return estName;
    }

    public void seteName(String esName) {
        this.estName = esName;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getEstPhoto() {
        return estPhoto;
    }

    public void setEstPhoto(int estPhoto) {
        this.estPhoto = estPhoto;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.estName + " ";
    }
}
```

The searchview and listview displays and can be clickable. But I don't know how when the user clicks from the list and load to a fragment or an activity. :(

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define a clickListener for your ListView in code:

```
    [your_list_view].setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);
```

Then define the method:

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
    String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString(); //text of position selected
} };
```

In your activity_main.xml you need to create a FrameLayout, for the Fragment to load:

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Inside the method you created for the ListView,you need to inflate your Fragment like this:

```
Fragment newFragment = new YourFragmentClass();
FragmentTransaction transaction = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Please see that "YourFragmentClass()" is the class when you handle the Fragment, this class is something like this:

```
public class FragmentMain extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //returning our layout file
    //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayoutfilename, container, false);


    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("Main");


}
}
```

And if you want to change activity, you just need to put this code in the onClickListener of your ListView:

```
startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,DestinationActivity.class));
```

Hope it helps :)

EDIT:
I managed to change activity and Fragment OnItemClick, the class should look like this:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Activity_list extends AppCompatActivity implements   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
EstablishmentAdapter adapter = null;
ArrayList<Establishments> establishments = null;
ListView myEstListView;
SearchView mySearchView = null ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    establishments = new ArrayList<>();
    establishments = populateEstablishmentsData(establishments);
    mySearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.mySearchView ) ;
    myEstListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myEstListView);
    adapter = new EstablishmentAdapter(this, establishments);
    myEstListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    myEstListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

    mySearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(getSupportActionBar() != null)
    {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

private ArrayList<Establishments> populateEstablishmentsData(ArrayList<Establishments> establishments) {
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Art Gallery", 1, R.drawable.art_gallery_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("ATM", 2, R.drawable.atm_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Bakery", 3, R.drawable.bakery_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Bank",4, R.drawable.bank_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Bar",5, R.drawable.bar_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Book Store",6, R.drawable.book_store_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Bus Station/Bus Terminal",7, R.drawable.bus_terminal_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Cafe",8, R.drawable.cafe_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Car Services",9, R.drawable.car_services_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Car Retail Store",10, R.drawable.car_services_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Cemetery",11, R.drawable.cemetery_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Department Store",12, R.drawable.department_store_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Electronics Store",13, R.drawable.electronic_store_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Fast Food Chain",14, R.drawable.fast_food_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Fire Station",15, R.drawable.fire_station_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Flower Shop",16, R.drawable.flowershop_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Gas Station",17, R.drawable.gas_station_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Government Office",18, R.drawable.gov_office_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Gym",19, R.drawable.gym_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Hospital",20, R.drawable.hospital_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Hotel",21, R.drawable.hotel_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Ice Cream Shop",22, R.drawable.ice_cream_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Insurance Agency",23, R.drawable.insurance_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Jewelry Store",24, R.drawable.jewelry_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Laundry Shop Services",25, R.drawable.laundry_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Library",26, R.drawable.library_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Museum",27, R.drawable.museum_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Park",28, R.drawable.park_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Pet Store",29, R.drawable.pet_store_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Pharmacy",30, R.drawable.pharmacy_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Place of Worship",31, R.drawable.place_of_worship_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Police Station",32, R.drawable.police_station_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Restaurant",33, R.drawable.restaurant_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("School",34, R.drawable.school_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Shoes Store",35, R.drawable.shoe_store_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Shopping Mall",36, R.drawable.shopping_mall_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Spa",10, R.drawable.spa_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Travel Agency",37, R.drawable.travel_service_icon));
    establishments.add(new Establishments("Zoo",38, R.drawable.zoo_icon));
    return establishments;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
    Establishments c = adapter.getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(Activity_list.this, " " + c.geteName() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //for some reason, it never enters this method when onItemClick :c

    //startActivity(new Intent(this, establishments[position].activityClass));
    // Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondFragment.class);
    //startActivity(intent);

    // android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home)
        finish();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
private void loadFragment(){
    Fragment fragment = new SecondFragment();

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
private void changeActivity(){
    startActivity(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class));
}
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Establishments c = adapter.getItem(arg2);
        Toast.makeText(Activity_list.this, " " + c.geteName() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //you decide if you want to change activity
        changeActivity();

        //or load a fragment
        loadFragment();

    }
};
}
```

Give it a try :)

Comment: `[your_list_view].setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);` where do i need to define this? I'm so sorry. I'm very new to android.

Comment: You define this in onCreate method of the Activity that handles the layout where the list view is, but first you define the variable like this:    ListView [your_list_view] = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.[your_list_view_id]);

Comment: Can I ask what the Textview is for? :) `private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
    String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString(); //text of position selected
} };`

Comment: When you tap a position in ListView, enters mDeviceclickListener in this case and in the paramms of this method you have the View you tapped, View v, so it's like parse the view into TextView where you can extract the text, so basically, it takes the String value of the position selected and puts into "info" variable for you to use :)

Comment: I'll post my codes. I have 3 classes for this project. `Activity_List` `EstablishmentAdapter` and `Establishments`. It's a list view that has a search view. @Josue Gramajo

Comment: thank you. I just hope someone can help. Thank you so much for taking the time.

Comment: @BlancheNeedsHelp I edit my original answer, hope it helps

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, this is for the fragments `private void loadFragment(){
    Fragment fragment = new SecondFragment();

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}`

Comment: and this is for the activity? `private void changeActivity(){
    startActivity(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class));
}`

Comment: welp... it crashed :(

Comment: `private void loadFragment(){
        Fragment fragment = new Second();

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }` the fragment fragment = new fragment.. i think this line makes it crash

Comment: You are right, those methods you describe do exactly what you write, about crash "Second" is the class that loads your fragment.xml and extends from Fragment right? In this particular case I recommend to you use change of activity instead of Fragment, it would get you out of many troubles, but if you still want to use Fragment, describe the Exception that you're getting

Comment: Yes but when it has that red lines when I wrote Second.class :/

Comment: The red lines mean that the class you are writing doesn't exist, you need to put your fragment class with his own name

Comment: my list is inside an activity class... what I'm supposed to do is after I clicked from the list, it goes to a fragment. Any idea?

Comment: Well in that case you only need to finish your activity in the moment you show the fragment, just put "finish();" when you draw your fragment